# How do I remove white space INSIDE CSS border? I want the border to be tight around the text

Tags: html, css, border

Here is my very basic test code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">

    <p style="border:1px solid red; font-size:10em; margin:0;">
    test</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that as I increase the font size, the more white space is put above and below the text.

Is there a way to get the border to wrap tight around the text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with `line-height`:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">

    <p style="border:1px solid red; font-size:10em; margin:0; line-height:0.5em">
    test</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree. You're going to want line-height to be below 1em (100%) because line-height of 100% includes some white space.

Comment: Thanks everyone. <br />

`line-height` is the key. And specifically, (@Vian Esterhuizen @lazycs)  making `line-height` less than 1em (100%) to decrease the white space. You have to fiddle about with the values to get it so that there's no white space, but it works.

Why is it that there is no mention of `line-height` as a property of paragraphs in the official [w3 documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/p.html)?

Comment: @Stevex, probably because it's nothing to do with paragraphs, particularly, it's a property of, pretty much, anything that can contain text :) [`line-height` at W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
p {
    padding: 0; /* reduces the space between the content, and the border, of the p element */
    line-height: 1.2em; /* to avoid the text being 'squashed' together */
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rG8JA/)

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for introducing me to `line-height`. For my particular problem though, setting `line-height` above 1em **increases** the white space! Setting it to < 1em (100%) instead **decreases** the white space. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CSS reset stylesheet makes things a lot easier for other browsers to handle, as many browser have their own defaults.

Just paste this huge line of CSS into your script, and it should look a bit more uniform (source: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/):

```
html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
```

Now, [@David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328825/how-do-i-remove-white-space-inside-css-border-i-want-the-border-to-be-tight-arou/5328853#5328853)'s answer might look uniform.

Comment: please excuse the edit, I just thought it'd make sense to link to the answer you reference. :)

Comment: Oh, that's okay. Just in case nobody finds it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the very useful tip! Seems such a simple solution to explicitly declare defaults for more uniformity across browsers.

Are there any disadvantages?

Comment: Not that I know of. I do this for every project I start, as it makes debugging a *lot* easier in the long run.